# Find $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\frac{f(x)-2\cdot x^2}{x-1}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that:
>   $$\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\frac{f^2(x)+f(x)-6}{x-1}}=5$$ If we know that
>   $$\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\frac{f(x)-2\cdot x^2}{x-1}}=a\in \mathbb{R}$$
>   find the value of *'a'* without using derivatives.

How can we solve this?

I see that we can easily factor the $f^2(x)+f(x)-6=(f(x)+3)\cdot (f(x)-2)$ but I don't understand how to move on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$a=\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\frac{f(x)-2\cdot x^2}{x-1}}=\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}}-2\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}}=\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}}-4$$

This tells you that
$$a+4=\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}}$$

Now write
$$f^2(x)+f(x)-6=(f(x)-2)(f(x)+3)$$
and use the above twice: once to get rid of the fraction and second time to deduce that $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)=2$.

Comment: I guess you have extra $-4$ in the second line.

Comment: @Caran-d'Ache Ty, fixed

Comment: I don't understand how to deduce that $\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{f(x)}=2$. Can you help me with this? I have reduced the fraction to $$\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{f(x)}=\frac{5}{a+4}-3$$

Comment: OK, I found it. I just say that $$\lim_\limits{x\to 1}{((f(x)-2)\cdot (f(x)+3))}=0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{5}{(a+4)^2}\cdot (-5\cdot a-15)=0 \Leftrightarrow 5\cdot a=-15 \Leftrightarrow a=-3$$ Thank you very much!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the shortest path, but I find it less "dangerous":

> First, we shall prove that $f$ has a limit when $x\to 1$.

From the equality
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-2x^2}{x-1}=a$$
we can say that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists some $\delta\in(0,\frac\epsilon{|a|+\epsilon})$ such that
$$0<|x-1|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{f(x)-2x^2}{x-1}-a\right|<\epsilon$$
or
$$0<|x-1|<\delta\implies|f(x)-2x^2|<|x-1|(|a|+\epsilon)<\epsilon$$
Therefore $\lim_{x\to 1}(f(x)-2x^2)=0$. Hence, $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$ does exist and is $2$. To show this, just put to work the $\epsilon-\delta$ machine together with the inequality $|f(x)-2|\le|f(x)-2x^2|+|2x^2-2|$.

> Now we use the first limit to calculate the second one.

The polynomial $X^2+X-6$ is reducible. In fact, it is $(X-2)(X+3)$. Then
$$\frac{f(x)^2+f(x)-6}{x-1}=\frac{(f(x)-2)(f(x)+3)}{x-1}$$

Furthermore,
$$\frac{f(x)-2x^2}{x-1}=\frac{f(x)-2+2-2x^2}{x-1}=\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}-2(x+1)$$
hence
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)-2}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{f(x)-2x^2}{x-1}+2x+2\right)=a+4$$

Finally
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f(x)^2+f(x)-6}{x-1}=5(a+4)$$
Thus, $a+4=1$ and $a=-3$.

Comment: very, very nice :)